# Issue with Python fetch all parsing

Tags: python, postgresql

In my python app getting data from DB by the below query,

```
cur = connM.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE useremail = '{}' ".format(userEmail)) 
user_record = cur.fetchall()
```

and from the response **user_record**, I am trying to get the only value which is in index 3 like below ;

```
value = [item[2] for item in user_record]
```

in **user_record**, I have the below value when I print it,

```
[(3, 'test@gmail.com', '00000000', 'Test', 'Test', '1234', '123456')]
```

however in **value** when I am printing it I am seeing below,

```
['00000000']
```

how I can assign a pure string value to the variable so I can use it after that in some conditions like;

```
if value == "00000000":
..
..
```

Comment: **Never** use python's formatting to construct SQL queries. You're asking for SQL injections. This example you've provided is absolutely 100% insecure.

Comment: what can be your advice here?

Comment: To not use them! Depending on what library you're using, there should exist a way to construct [*parameterized queries*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query). In psycopg, you can do [this](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html) for example.

Comment: Ok thx, i will have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchall` returns a list of tuples of query result. To get the third element and also to do the comparison you can either iterate over the `user_record` and access the `2nd` index.

```
for item in user_record:
    if item[2] == "00000000":
        # TODO
```

or If you are sure that the result will always contains single element, you can directly index the element,

```
if user_record[0][2] == "00000000":
    pass
```